# WiX Installer failed to parse condition

Tags: xml, parsing, wix, conditional-statements

I am trying to create a WiX installer that makes sure the user is on Windows 7 and doesn't already have .NET Framework 4.5 installed. Below is both the error code and the XML/WXS Code in the bundle. I'm at a loss as to why it doesn't understand this unless its all the parentheses. But, without them it doesn't understand what NOT is.

**Code:**

```
<Chain>
    <ExePackage Id="PrePackage" SourceFile="dotNetFx45_Full_Setup.exe" InstallCondition="(VersionNT &gt;= v6.1) AND NOT (Net4FullVersion &gt;= 4.5)" />
    <MsiPackage Id="MainPackage" SourceFile="SampleFirst.msi" InstallCondition="VersionNT &gt;= v6.1" />
</Chain>
```

**Error:**

```
[0A20:0954][2014-06-23T12:07:14]e000: Error 0x8007000d: Failed to parse condition "(VersionNT >= v6.1) AND NOT (Net4FullVersion >= 4.5)". Unexpected character at position 49.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Having experimented locally, it looks like the Net4FullVersion needs to have its version number quoted; which means in your case the quotes will have to be escaped:

```
 <ExePackage Id="PrePackage" SourceFile="dotNetFx45_Full_Setup.exe" InstallCondition="(VersionNT >= v6.1) AND NOT (Net4FullVersion >= &quot;4.5&quot;)" />
```

Comment: Ok I tried updating my '>' symbols as you suggested (also updated code in my question) but I am still getting the exact same error but with updated time stamp.

Comment: I'm assuming if I use = instead of >= it will only evaluate to true if it finds 4.5 and not necessarily 4.5.2 or theoretically 4.6.

Comment: I'm just looking at this locally, but it looks like the Net4FullVersion is to blame...

Comment: ok - updated. I suspect my previous point about escaping the "greater than" is not necessary.

Answer (score 2):

Versions in Burn are distinct from strings and numbers, unlike how Windows Installer handles versions. That means you need to use the "v" prefix, as in `VersionNT >= v6.1`.